# What should be the value of state.checkpoints.num-retained with Incremental checkpointing enabled

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

As per Flink documentation by default value of state.checkpoints.num-retained is 1 which means Flink only retails one checkpoint in memory. We have enabled Incremental checkpointing in our job. I wanted to know what value we should set for state.checkpoints.num-retained with incremental checkpoint. I am confused how does this incremental checkpoint work if we go with default configuration of 1 where it will just save the last one checkpoint

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think the meaning of `state.checkpoints.num-retained` is related to incremental checkpoints.

This parameter is used when you want to keep the last few checkpoints for some redundancy. If the last checkpoint (by default it is the only one) is broken, we can use the earlier ones.

I think a bit of confusion with the meaning of this parameter is caused by the article which describes incremental checkpoints https://flink.apache.org/2018/01/30/managing-large-state-in-apache-flink-an-intro-to-incremental-checkpointing.

Incremental checkpoints work regardless of this parameter.

My impression, although I might be mistaken, is that the components of a incremental checkpoint (incremental sst files of RockDB) could be used by multiple consecutive checkpoints. As a result, they are not written to the `chk-X` directory, which holds, by definition, 'exclusive' data, belonging to only a specific checkpoint. Instead, they are saved in the `shared` directory, which stores data used by many checkpoints.